# Cakephp 3 : How to detect mobile in controller by requestHandler?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need detect mobile in controller for a condition. I have tried below code in my controller.

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}
```

Then I have written below code in index method

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->is('mobile')) 
{     
  //condition 1 
}else {
 //condition 2 
}
```

Here I get the error

```
Error: Call to undefined method Cake\Controller\Component\RequestHandlerComponent::is()
```

How can  mobile detect in controller ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The request handler isn't necessary for that since [all the request handler does is proxy the request object](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Controller/Component/RequestHandlerComponent.php#L353-L357):

```
public function isMobile()
{
    $request = $this->request;
    return $request->is('mobile') || $this->accepts('wap');
}
```

The controller also has direct access to the request object, so the code in the question can be rewritten as:

```
/* Not necessary
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
} 
*/    

public function example()
{
    if ($this->request->is('mobile')) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that will be

```
$this->RequestHandler->isMobile()
```

Comment: both the examples works, for $this->RequestHandler->isMobile() we need load "RequestHandler" component.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 3 uses mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib lib

In bootstrap.php added 2 types of detection 'mobile', 'tablet'

You can use it:

```
    if ($this->request->is('mobile')) {
       // ...
    }
    elseif ($this->request->is('tablet')) {
       // ...
    }
    else {
       // ...
    }
```